# What versions of Perl support $#$ sigil?

Tags: perl, range

I discovered that this is how you use ranges with an arrayref:

```
@$aref[2..$#$aref]
```

So, the situation is that I don't have access to all these different perl environments (to test it), but if the code, *which will eventually get compiled on all of them,* fails to compile, I get in trouble.

Perl versions: `5.16.2`, `5.10.1`, and `5.8.8`

Anybody know?

It's not physically possible to google for perl syntax intricacies without getting clever. I'm not clever enough to do it for this.

P.S. Did you know? `@$arr_ref[-3..$#$arr_ref]` gives you the last three elements, then the entire array is appended to it. That's apparently what `[-3..5]` means: give elements `-3` (= 3) to `5`, then append `0` thru `5`.

It's because perl doesn't deal with it in a sensible way unless both range indices are the same sign: to get a slice that contains the 5th from last to the end, you just use `@arr[-5..-1]`.

Comment: It is sensible — `-3 .. 5` is the series -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, ... 5, and you are asking for a slice of those indices.  **You happen to have a six element array**, and so the element at index -3 happens also to be the same as at index 3.

Comment: It makes more sense now that I know that ranges are a thing on their own, and serve a purpose outside of array slicing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This notation isn't actually special; it's just how the array slice, arrayref, `..`, and `$#` notations work, and you're putting them all together straightforwardly. But to answer your question, yes, it works in Perl 5.8.8:

```
$ perl -v | grep . | head -1
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64-64int

$ perl -e '$aref = [1 .. 5]; print "<$_>\n" foreach @$aref[2..$#$aref]'
<3>
<4>
<5>
```

(and even in much earlier versions).

Answer (score 4):

`$#array` returns the last index of array `@array`. Similarly, `$#{ $aref }` returns the last index of the array referenced by `$aref`. This can be shortened to `$#$aref`.

`$x .. $y` is the range operator. It returns the numbers from `$x` up to `$y` inclusively. (It works for some strings too.) For example, `-3 .. 5` means `-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

`@array[...]` is an array slice. It returns the elements of array `@array` specified by the index expression. Similarly, `@{ $aref }[...]` returns the elements of array referenced by  `$aref`. This can be shortened to `@$aref[...]`.

All of these features predate 5.8.8. They even predate 5.6.0.

```
$ perl -v | grep 'This is'
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i386-linux-thread-multi

$ perl -le'@array = qw( a b c d e ); print @array[2..$#array]'
cde

$ perl -le'$aref = [qw( a b c d e )]; print @{ $aref }[2..$#{ $aref }]'
cde

$ perl -le'$aref = [qw( a b c d e )]; print @$aref[2..$#$aref]'
cde
```

---

Note that more powerful slicing expressions are currently being discussed by the developers of Perl.

Right now, there's no easy way to do the following without using that temporary array.

```
sub f { ... }
my @a = f();
my @b = @a[2..$#a];
```

Comment: I like how Python does it. Turn the `..` 90 degrees.

Comment: `:` would conflict with the conditional operator (`EXPR ? EXPR : EXPR`)

Answer (score 3):

The `$#` syntax (used to get the index of the last element in an array) has been part of Perl's syntax since the dawn of the 5.x line. Actually, the `$#array` syntax has been around since at least Perl 4 but references (and thus the `$#$aref` syntax) didn't exist until Perl 5.

While it isn't trivially searchable, if you want to know when a change appeared in Perl you need to look at the [perldelta](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html) documentation for each version.